# I can't do npx react-native run-android, Java error; Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. LINUX

Tags: java, android, linux, react-native, android-studio

*There were lots of Mapping new... logs, so i deleted a big chunk, because I exceeded the available characters*

(I'm not sure if this is the problem) It says it's something related to the licences, but I already accepted them all, as far as I know.

In the images I show you what I've installed throught Android Studio, everything seems fine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
npx react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 863 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 2 workers...
info JS server already running.
/bin/sh: 1: /home/u/platform-tools/adb: not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Observed package id 'system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86' in inconsistent location '/home/u/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86' (Expected '/home/u/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86')
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/home/u/Android/Sdk/tools' (Expected '/home/u/tools')
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 in /home/u/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 30 in /home/u/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 30 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;30.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2
     platforms;android-30 Android SDK Platform 30
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
  
  Using Android SDK: /home/u

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 38s

error Failed to install the app. Please accept all necessary Android SDK licenses using Android SDK Manager: "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses".
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;30.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2
     platforms;android-30 Android SDK Platform 30
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
  
  Using Android SDK: /home/u

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 38s

    at makeError (/home/u/Desktop/workdir/Math_App/mathapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /home/u/Desktop/workdir/Math_App/mathapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/home/u/Desktop/workdir/Math_App/mathapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/home/u/Desktop/workdir/Math_App/mathapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically indicates it's missing `build-tools;30.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 platforms;android-30 Android SDK Platform 30`

Install them throught Android-Studio, and everything should work.

---

Addionaty to that, I'd another problem (probably unrelated to the one on top, but I'll still add it here)

So, now if I try again `npx react-native run-android` the following error pops us

```
[adb]: Cannot run program "/home/u/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory
```

`platform-tools` lives inside `~/Android/Sdk`, not inside `~/` .

Basically it means that the path is wrong. [Fix for that is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71182902/java-cannot-find-platform-tools-adb-building-app-with-react-native/71182903#71182903)