# Java cannot find '/platform-tools/adb' (Building app with react-native)

Tags: java, android, flutter, react-native, adb

I run `npx react-native run-android` and I get this

This seems to be the problem, It's looking for platform tools in `~/` and not in `~/Android/Sdk`

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/u/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory
> `

*You can ignore this, stack won't let me post this if I don't add more text, but I think it's already a good explanation*

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libbetter.so, libc++_shared.so, libevent-2.1.so, libevent_core-2.1.so, libevent_extra-2.1.so, libfabricjni.so, libfb.so, libfbjni.so, libflipper.so, libfolly_futures.so, libfolly_json.so, libglog.so, libglog_init.so, libimagepipeline.so, libjsc.so, libjscexecutor.so, libjsi.so, libjsijniprofiler.so, libjsinspector.so, liblogger.so, libmapbufferjni.so, libnative-filters.so, libnative-imagetranscoder.so, libreact_codegen_rncore.so, libreact_debug.so, libreact_nativemodule_core.so, libreact_render_animations.so, libreact_render_attributedstring.so, libreact_render_componentregistry.so, libreact_render_core.so, libreact_render_debug.so, libreact_render_graphics.so, libreact_render_imagemanager.so, libreact_render_leakchecker.so, libreact_render_mapbuffer.so, libreact_render_mounting.so, libreact_render_runtimescheduler.so, libreact_render_scheduler.so, libreact_render_telemetry.so, libreact_render_templateprocessor.so, libreact_render_textlayoutmanager.so, libreact_render_uimanager.so, libreact_utils.so, libreactconfig.so, libreactnativeblob.so, libreactnativejni.so, libreactnativeutilsjni.so, libreactperfloggerjni.so, librrc_image.so, librrc_modal.so, librrc_progressbar.so, librrc_root.so, librrc_scrollview.so, librrc_slider.so, librrc_switch.so, librrc_text.so, librrc_textinput.so, librrc_unimplementedview.so, librrc_view.so, libturbomodulejsijni.so, libyoga.so.

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
31 actionable tasks: 31 executed
Note: /home/u/Desktop/workdir/Math_App/mathapp/android/app/src/debug/java/com/mathapp/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[adb]: Cannot run program "/home/u/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/u/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: /home/u/Desktop/workdir/Math_App/mathapp/android/app/src/debug/java/com/mathapp/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[adb]: Cannot run program "/home/u/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/u/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 4s

    at makeError (/home/u/Desktop/workdir/Math_App/mathapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /home/u/Desktop/workdir/Math_App/mathapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/home/u/Desktop/workdir/Math_App/mathapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/home/u/Desktop/workdir/Math_App/mathapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check where your $ANDROID_HOME variable is pointing to.

`echo $ANDROID_HOME`

If must be equal to the path of `Android/Sdk`, usually at `~/Android/Sdk`

A solution, if you know where the variable `ANDROID_HOME` is (maybe `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`):

Go to the file you've the var `ANDROID_HOME` and edit it so it looks like this

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

After you changed them, do `source .bashrc` or `source {whatever file they're on}` and it should work (it works on the terminal you did it, it, do it in whatever terminal you want it to work, if it's on `.bashrc` it'll work next time you restart without doing source)

That's how it's done if Android is installed in ~/ (you can check out by doing `cd`, and then `ls`, `Android` should appear, if it didn't, change `$HOME` for the direction of where you installed it).

If you don't have those variables at all: just open `~/.bashrc` and add them to the file. And do the same as it's explained before.

And yeah, that's it. I'd appreciate if someone translated this to the *Windows* and *Mac* way.